# How can I move data using an AWS Glue ETL Job from S3/Data Catalog to Oracle RDS Database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue

I have a simple proof-of-concept that I'm trying to complete, in which I want to take CSV data from S3 or a Data Catalog built from that S3 bucket and move it to a table in an Oracle RDS database. I've created a few different jobs in an attempt to find the correct configuration, but I can't seem to get it.

The ETL job is simple: the source is a CSV file selected from my S3 bucket, which links to an "ApplyMapping" transform step that maps the source fields to their respective Target keys and Data types, which links to an "Oracle SQL table" data target.

I'm able to select the RDS database in my last step, but the confusion starts when I try to select the table in that step definition. This was an empty database before I started this process, and the only table that appears in the dropdown is the name of the database, but with underscores rather than hyphens.

> Database name: dummy-user-data-1
>
> Table available for selection in dropdown: dummy_user_data_1

When I select that table and run the job, it completes successfully. After connecting to the database and attempting to select the data from that table, I initially found that the table didn't even exist.

In an attempt to help the job out, we created a table named "dummy_user_data_1" in that database with the expected schema and tried again. Once again, we found that no data had been inserted into the "dummy_user_data_1" table. I've also tried to create an ETL script job based on the generated script from this and other attempts using a connector, but that results in a 400 error.

> ... failed to execute with exception Unable to resolve any valid connection....

I would test the connector from the Connections page, but that option is no longer available and there is no updated documentation for this at the time of posting.

If someone has accomplished something similar to this recently, please let me know. I've found nothing but examples from the previous iteration of AWS Glue, and it appears that the documentation hasn't been fully updated for this new version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the data is saved to the csv files, are the files the in the same shape of the tables in the target endpoint, meaning no more transformations needed prior to storing in RDS?

Comment: @RossBush yes - although as I mentioned, the table didn't even exist when I first attempted to run the job. We later created the table with the same schema that was expected based on the CSV data.

Comment: ddores95 - Not trying to sway you from your current solution, however, this would be a simple task for DMS. Pull data from S3 endpoint into and RDS endpoint, with or without ongoing replication.

Comment: @RossBush I sincerely appreciate any tips for other solutions, however I've been tasked with trying to prove this specific workflow. I've already determined that I could easily create a tool to accomplish this without all of the confusion. You know how it is ;)
I'll be taking a look at your suggestion for possible fallback workflows. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it could be a schema confusion issue. What tool are you using to inspect Oracle? Can you browse all of the available schemas? The data may have dropped into an unexpected schema, one that you might not even have access to. Keep in mind the Oracle hierarchy is Database > has many schemas > has many objects. But many drivers might call an Oracle schema a "database" or a "Catalog"